# Can i use the column in order by clasue

Tags: oracle

I have specifiec requirement .Actually this is my query. here amount is a column in my table.but i did not mention the amount column in select statement.here can i use this column in oreder by clause.

```
SELECT stud_name, stud_roll, stud_prg
FROM programcl 
ORDER BY 3, amount, 1;
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: BTW Ordering by static values does not make sense

Comment: In the example, he is not ordering by static values. The 1 and 3 relate to the 1st and 3rd columns in the SELECT list. This is the way it works in Oracle anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can mix both positional and named assignments in your `ORDER BY` clause.

The positional assignments must appear in your `SELECT` list. The named assignments do not have to.

Answer (score 0):

```
can i use this column in oreder by clause.
```

Yes of course you can use a different column in **order by** clause that wasn't selected from your select statement.

For example

```
select col1 from tab1
order by col2;
```

by this way you get results from **col1** which will be displayed on order of **col2**.

**Its Worth trying**